# Exporting figure as pdf using savefig() messes up axis background in matplotlib

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to change the axis background on a plot where several `imshow()` calls render images in various locations via the `extent` parameter.

When I save a pdf of the figure using `savefig()`, I lose the background color if the axis displays more than one image. Note that this doesn't happen when exporting a png of the same figure.

Here's a minimal script illustrating the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=True)

ax[0].imshow(rand(15,15), extent=[0, 2, 15, 0], \
            cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='Nearest')
ax[0].set_axis_bgcolor('k')

ax[1].imshow(rand(15,15), extent=[0, 2, 15, 0], \
            cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='Nearest')
ax[1].imshow(rand(15,15), extent=[4, 6, 15, 0], \
            cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='Nearest')
ax[1].set_axis_bgcolor('k')

ax[2].imshow(rand(15,15), extent=[0, 2, 15, 0], \
            cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='Nearest')
ax[2].imshow(rand(15,15), extent=[4, 6, 15, 0], \
            cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='Nearest')
ax[2].imshow(rand(15,15), extent=[8, 10, 15, 0], \
            cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto', interpolation='Nearest')
ax[2].set_axis_bgcolor('k')

ax[-1].set_xlim([0, 12])
fig.savefig('test.pdf', format='PDF')
fig.savefig('test.png', format='PNG')
```

This is the pdf output of the script (the eps output is the same):

[image: test.pdf]

And this is the expected output of the script (saved as a png):

[image: test.png]

Have I bumped into a matplotlib bug, or is there some command I'm missing that will fix the pdf output?

EDIT: I've re-plotted the figures with a default `matplotlibrc`.

Comment: I just tried running your script and the .pdf and .png versions both have the correct backgrounds. Which version of `matplotlib` are you using? Mine is `1.2.0`.

Comment: I'm running 1.2.1 at the moment, but have tried it on an older version with the same result. I'm also running it on OS X.

Comment: It looks like you're using some fancy math-style serif fonts which are different to the default. I wonder if some setting defined in your `matplotlibrc` file might be messing up PDF rendering. Maybe try renaming the file so that you use `matplotlib` with the default parameters? And another thought - does it render correctly as an EPS file?

Comment: @ali_m: Those fonts are rendered by LaTeX. I've renamed the `matplotlibrc` configuration file and uploaded updated figures. The EPS output is the same as the PDF output. I'm beginning to believe this might have to do with the `MacOSX` backend.

Comment: This question was due to a bug that has since been fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ended up being a matplotlib bug.

When rendering more than one image on the same axes, a composite image is created that does not have a transparent background when rendering to pdf, so the background color of the axes does not show through.

This got resolved as part of [an issue I opened in the matplotlib's GitHub repo](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1894).

Answer (score 2):

Look into your `matplotlibrc`. There is a section of options starting with `savefig` which define how your saved figure will look like. Even default `matplotlibrc` have this section.

There is also a similar question: [matplotlib savefig() plots different from show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906365/matplotlib-savefig-plots-different-from-show)

Comment: This isn't the problem though. I'm not comparing the output of `show()` to the output of `savefig()`, but rather that of the latter to a choice of output formats. My problem ended up being a matplotlib bug.