# matplotlib savefig not the same as plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im using a matplotlib style sheet which correctly renders the specified serif font when I use 'plot()' but when I try and save the plot with 'savefig()' I receive an error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1282: UserWarning: findfont: Font family [u'serif'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

I've looked at using different backends from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906365/matplotlib-savefig-plots-different-from-show) but it I can't figure out how to configure a font setting for both the 'plot()' and the 'savefig()' functions.  Thanks!