# Color of surface plots turning black after saving- Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why will my surface plot colour change from the 1st to the second in terms of colour?

[image: pre-save]

[image: post-save]

The following is my code for the plot:

```
def Plots3d(U):

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    y, x = U.shape

    Y = np.arange(0, y, 1)
    X = np.arange(0, x, 1)
    Y, X = np.meshgrid(Y, X)
    Z = U[Y, X]
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, 
        linewidth=0.7, antialiased=False, cmap = cm.summer)

    plt.xlabel('Stock Price Nodes')
    plt.ylabel('Timesteps')
    plt.title('Analytical solution surface for 0 <= t <= 2')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: what's the difference in how you created the two plots?

Comment: Theyre the same plot, however the first is a screenshot of what it looks like before i save it. The second is after the save. Sorry i wasnt clear on that

Comment: What format / size are you saving it as, have you tried increasing the image size? It looks like the dots are too small to be shown and are being wiped out when saving the image.

Comment: see this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906365/matplotlib-savefig-plots-different-from-show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a resolution problem: the lines in the saved plot are too thick and are dominating the figure when saved, turning it black. The default resolution of a saved figure and a figure produced with `plt.show` are probably different in your `matplotlibrc` file.

You could try either increasing the resolution (the *dots per square inch*, or `dpi`) or decreasing the linewidth.

A few possible options for you:

**Increase dpi with `rcParams`**

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
# this changes the dpi of figures saved from plt.show() 
rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300 
# this changes the dpi of figures saved from plt.savefig()
rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300
```

**Increase dpi during savefig**

If you don't want to use rcParams, you can just increase the dpi as you save the figure:

```
plt.savefig('myfigure.png', dpi=300)
```

**Decreasing linewidth**

Alternatively, you could try decreasing the linewidth of the surface plot

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, 
    linewidth=0.3, antialiased=False, cmap = cm.summer)
```