# OffsetImage shows up different on screen and in PDF when aligning the image to the figure border

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to insert a scaled image on a figure and align it to right figure border. The following works fine in the interactive windows and when saving as png,
but when saving as a pdf the image is too to the left. How can i get the correct behavior for both cases? This happens also if the savefig and figure settings are identical.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
image = np.ones((200, 200))
ob = OffsetImage(image, zoom=0.5)
rend = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
w, h, x, d =  ob.get_extent(rend)
fig.images.append(ob)
ob.set_offset((fig.bbox.xmax-w, 0))
plt.show()
fig.savefig("bla.pdf", dpi=100)
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code, being more explicit about padding and bounding box, gives the same for png and pdf for me (matplotlib 1.4.3, python 2.7).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
image = np.ones((200, 200))
ob = OffsetImage(image, zoom=0.5)
rend = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
w, h, x, d =  ob.get_extent(rend)
fig.images.append(ob)
ob.set_offset((fig.bbox.xmax-w, 0))
fig.savefig("bla.pdf",figsize=(8,6),
                       bbox_inches='tight', 
                       pad_inches=0)
```

The version of your code (even with `plt.show()` removed) gave an empty pdf document for me. As to why the above works, I guess it may be a bug with `matplotlib` or possibility a difference in coordinate [system](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) used in saving the pdf vs. the more wysiwyg display/png figure. Could also be matplotlib template, in which case this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906365/matplotlib-savefig-plots-different-from-show) may help...

Comment: It only seems to work on the first glance: the image is still misplaced, but due to `bbox_inches =  'tight'` it will be included by increasing the size of the pdf.

Comment: The actual problem seem to be caused by the fact that pdfs are always calculated with 72 dpi and OffsetImage ignores that.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise it still wasn't right. PDF apparently doesn't use the dpi setting except for resolution of raster graphics. Does setting `plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))` help as this should impact the PDF.