# Apply colormap on grayscale image and save it

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, colormap

I want to apply a plt colormap to a medical grayscale image (14bit (16383 is the maximum pixel value) image stored as np.uint16) and save it as a single channel grayscale image. However when I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rand_img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=16383,size=(500,500),dtype=np.uint16)
# rand_img.shape = (500,500)
cm = plt.cm.gist_yarg
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=((2**14)-1))
img = cm(norm(rand_img))
# img.shape = (500,500,4)
```

the resulting img.shape is a 4 channel (rgba?) image whereas what I want is a one channel image. The first 3 channels are all the same so I could just slice out one channel and use it. However the image turns out significantly darker as when I display it with, e.g.,

```
plt.imshow(rand_img, cmap=plt.cm.gist_yarg)
```

**So how can I apply the colormap and save the image so that it looks exactly like when I use plt.imshow?**

PS: When I use plt.imsave with the colormap the saved image looks as expected, however it is still stores as a 4 channel image and not as a single channel image.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain that the difference you are seeing is coming from the default `dpi` setting in `plt.savefig()`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906365/matplotlib-savefig-plots-different-from-show) for details.  Since the default DPI is 100, it is likely that the difference you are seeing comes from down-sampling during image saving.  Trying `plt.savefig()` with the default DPI setting on your example, I can clearly see that the fine details are missing.

Modifying your code slightly, I can take your example and get two reasonably close looking plots:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

SAVEFIG_DPI = 1000
np.random.seed(1000)  # Added to make example repeatable

rand_img = np.random.randint(low=0, high=16383, size=(500, 500), dtype=np.uint16)
cm = plt.cm.gist_yarg
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=((2**14) - 1))
norm_cm_img = cm(norm(rand_img))

plt.imshow(norm_cm_img)
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi = SAVEFIG_DPI)

plt.imshow(norm_cm_img)
plt.show()
```

I get the following output, with `show()` on the left, and the image file on the right:

[image]

It's worth noting that I did try using `fig.dpi` as suggested in the linked question, but I was not able to get results that looked as close as this using that approach.